# xcode match first char of requestURL scheme

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I'm parsing UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked to launch Safari, dial a number etc.

Occasionally there will be a named anchor that I want to jump down the UIwebview, but also want to check it's not a redundant file link left in the HTML.

Solution is to check wether the link starts with a #

I'm using this it checks if # exists not if the links starts with #

```
NSURL *requestURL = [request URL];

if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

    if ([[requestURL scheme] isEqualToString: @"file" ]) {

        NSLog(@"I think it's a file", nil);

        NSString *urlString = [requestURL absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"Url as string: %@", urlString);

        if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"#"].location != NSNotFound) {

            // Do nothing, let it be handled by the web view


        } else {

            UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                      initWithTitle: @"Link Error" 
                                      message:@"Sorry!, don't seem to be able to open this link" 
                                      delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [errorView show];
            [errorView release];

        }


    }
}
```

Is there a way of only matching the first character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 
    if ([[requestURL scheme] substringWithRange:NSRangeMake(0,1)] isEqualTo:@"#")

Note: untested, let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Joel... I totally misunderstand [requestURL scheme] when I posted... it always returns 'file' when a local url is used ("local.pdf" or "#jumptome"). I've edited my original question to actually work but it still only checks for a #. Which means an external link with a named anchor would load within the web view, I only want local named anchors to load.... (thanks for answering tho, good to know NSRangeMake for future ref)